# Getting the email body using python

Tags: python, email

I'm quite new at this, but I've been trying to get the email body using python and I've tried almost all of the examples out there and I was able, with:

```
original = email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode('utf-8'), policy=policy.default)

         data1 = original.get_body('text/plain')
```

to get this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

SGkNCg==
```

in which the last line is actual my email body encoded with base64 but what I'm trying to do now is to actually get just the last line:

```
SGkNCg==
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was pretty simple, just had to use: `get_payload()`